# Configuring WSO2 with TIBCO EMS

Tags: java, wso2, tibco-ems, wso2-esb

I am trying to configure EMS with WSO2 and am using the following guide from WSO2.

https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB460/Configure+with+Tibco+EMS

Step three suggests the following.

*3. Copy the TIBCO EMS client jars to /repository/components/lib directory.*

I have tried copying all the jars in my EMS client folder, but I get the following error when I restart WSO2

*Caused by: javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Failed to create InitialConte
xt using factory specified in hash table. [Root exception is java.lang.ClassNotF
oundException: class
          com.tibco.tibjms.naming.TibjmsInitialContextFactory
        not found]
        at org.wso2.carbon.context.internal.CarbonContextDataHolder$CarbonInitia*

Has anyone been able to successfully WSO2 with EMS? If so can they confirm which jars were required?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it working. Here's a list of the jars I copied over. Using WSO2 v4.8 and EMS v8.0.

[image: solution]